# How to save a decimal number from c# to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, decimal

I'm having a problem when I try to save a decimal number from c# to sql database. First of all I have string that I convert to decimal and when I try to save that decimal to sql database something goes wrong. For example if I try to save 3.24, in database it shows as 324.00 this is the part of the code please help... I have already tried changig types from decimal to numeric and instead of convert.ToDecima decimal.Parse

```
        decimal cijena_uzine = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

        try
        {
            spremi_cijenu_obroka.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Vrsta_Obroka set cijena="+ cijena_uzine + " where Šifra_Obroka=1 ;", spremi_cijenu_obroka);
```

Comment: What is the text in your `textBox1`?

Comment: Please rewrite your code to be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hard-code the string, print out the value of `cijena_uzine` somewhere so you can see what the decimal is as a string, and then write it to the db.

Comment: going to need more info, but I suspect your conversion is not giving you the number you think.

Comment: off topic but coding like this - you are opening yourself up for SQL injection attacks!  use parametrized queries.

Comment: Could be your ui is set properly but using a comma for decimal point and that is being lost in translation. Does your input field look like 10,56 or 10.56?

Comment: tnx for the advice but it's a database on my computer and I'm using this for some sort of learning how to code... I eneter the number in textbox and then press the button to initiate action. I tried with dot like 3.24 and with comma like 3,24

Comment: When you initiate the action for the button you will need to take into account the threads.currentCulture.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing but you probably enter the number as `3,24` with comma as decimal separator (as most countries in Europe do).

This converts to `324` when you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat`.

Change you code to below to use your culture:

```
decimal cijena_uzine = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Good call.  Once you mentioned it, I tried `decimal.Parse("3,00")` and it does in fact return 300 (in my culture).  (though IMO that *should* result in a parse error, since the comma isn't in the correct place)

Comment: It doesn't work...still the same, I tried before entering the numbers as 3,24 and 3.24 result is the same :(

Comment: So what is the value of `cijena_uzine` when you debug?

Comment: @KirkWoll Comma is the thousand separator, that's why it returns it like that.

Comment: @Szymon, yes, I know that. :)  But while `1,000` is legit, `1,00` looks like one doesn't know what the comma ("thousand") separator is for. ;)

Comment: when I debug after conversion cijena_uzine is 424 when it should be 4.24

Comment: so the problem is in conversion

Comment: also if I use antoher variable decimal bla= 3.24m; and when I try to use that in sql query i catch an exception that says incorrect syntax near 24

Answer (score 0):

I left the variable as a string and it somehow works...

```
string cijena_uzine = textBox1.Text;             
        try
        {
            spremi_cijenu_obroka.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Vrsta_Obroka set cijena=" +cijena_uzine + " where Šifra_Obroka=1 ;", spremi_cijenu_obroka);
```